# Django tutorial path: TEMPLATE_PATH dir on a Mac networked computer

Tags: django, templates, filepath

I'm (slowly!) working my way through the Django tutorial, and I've reached the point in [Part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/) where I'm supposed to set the template_dir. I'm on a Mac (at work) where my user profile resides on a server, and I can't figure out how to set the path.

The tutorial files are in a folder called "tutorialshell", inside a folder called "Django," which is a first-level file inside my user folder "mattshepherd". That folder is the native folder when I launch the Terminal, for instance: it always starts me inside "mattshepherd".

I've tried

```
"~/Django/tutorialshell/templates"
```

and

```
"home/Django/tutorialshell/templates"
```

with no luck so far. I imagine there's some trick to doing this, as the files I'm trying to link to are on the network drive in my user folder, not on my local hard drive. Advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the absolute, not relative path. If you go to `~/Django/tutorialshell/templates` in your terminal and then type `pwd`, it will tell you the full path to that folder. That's the value you should enter for the path.

**Also**: I assume you're actually talking about `TEMPLATE_DIRS`? If so, keep in mind that it's a *list* of paths, so it should look like:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "/path/to/Django/tutorialshell/templates", # don't forget that trailing comma!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`/Users/mattshepherd/Django/tutorialshell/templates`

Please keep in mind that there is a LIST of template directories as mentioned by Jordan.  The above location should work.  In mac the user home directories are located at `/Users/` + `yourusername`

It might be /home/ if /Users/ does not work.

Comment: In my experience home directories on Macs are usually stored in `/Users/`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you need the absolute path. But i would really suggest you to use relative path. It will make your code much more flexible. There are many ways to do it, this is what i usually do:

```
import os
ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

then for the templates just do:

```
os.path.join(ROOT, 'templates')
```

You said you are using a Mac but you can make your code even more flexible by replacing "//" with "/" in the case you are using windows.